# How to install apache-poi on ubuntu

Tags: java, apache-poi

poi jars available on my classpath for execution of one of my jars. I have dowloaded the apache-poi package but I dont know what to do with it do I just dump the folder into the java lib folder?

Comment: Are you using Maven/Ivy/something else?

Comment: Im using maven to deploy but this file that im trying to run is separate from my maven project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1. Using Maven central repository**

I suggest you to use a dependency from the Maven central repository by puting this at your pom.xml. (Just like Benoit say), this will download it automatically to the Maven local repository ([user_directory]/.m2/repository folder).

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
    <version>3.9</version>
</dependency>
```

**2. Installing your own JAR file**

If you really want to use the separated JAR, then maybe, you can install it as a dependency in your Maven local repository by using the Maven Install plugin [See the usage page of the plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-install-plugin/usage.html):

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=c:\the-poi-1.0.jar -DgroupId=separated.lib 
-DartifactId=the-poi -Dversion=1.0 -Dpackaging=jar
```

And adding in your pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>separated.lib</groupId>
      <artifactId>the-poi</artifactId>
      <version>1.0</version>
 </dependency>
```

**3. Setting the classpath**

Or even you can use the ext folder of your Java installation. [See the Oracle's Java tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/ext/basics/install.html)

What about setting a classpath? Here are some useful tutorial to stting your classpath: [Using the underlying SO capabilities](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/paths.html) or [Using Eclipse IDE](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/reference/preferences/java/buildpath/ref-preferences-classpath-variables.htm)

Hope this help...

Comment: The error I had seemed to have to do with the classpath or possible where my libraries where placed. As I was transfering my .jar file to a remote ftp. When I added the correct class path and moved the lib direcory from my build server as well it started working.

Answer (score 1):

The best would be to add a depency in your POM for POI:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
    <version>3.9</version>
</dependency>
```

Or yes you can just copy the jar in the lib folder manually.